# How to install app with run file in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: installation, sync

Downloaded Copy application (dropbox alternative) for Linux https://www.copy.com/install/ 
Archive contains variant of GUI binaries with .run file.

I successfully executed it, but after reset OS app does not auto-start with and I cant find it with search.

I suppose that application needs to be installed somehow

Please advise how to install this application

I am novice with Linux so please make instructions as clear as possible.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the archive, and I have found no `.run` file. Instead, I have read the included `README` file which I actually found quite straightforward.

There are three programs:

1. `CopyAgent` -- it will display a nice GUI login screen and (probably) will become a tray icon. Could not test it, since I have no Copy account.
2. `CopyConsole` -- a headless (no output, no GUI) process that can run in background and manage your synchronisation.
3. `CopyCmd` -- a command line interface

If unsure, use `CopyAgent` by clicking it. There is no need to install it. It will just run.

P.S. Um, apparently running `sudo CopyAgent -installOverlay` installs a Nautilus overlay (which I guess allows to show which files are synced, which not). I think it does not replace running the CopyAgent itself.